# Rename the incoming files which are having 001,002 and 003 as file type

Tags: batch-file

I have one path which receives files named:

```
CYT1TXT.001
CYT1TXT.002
```

…and so on

But the service which has to pick these files is not recognizing the file type because of the dot involved here.

So can anyone please provide me any solution to first rename the file to:

```
CYT1TXT001
CYT1TXT002
```

by removing the dot and then moving it to some other folder.

Regards

Comment: Stack Overflow does not provide batch files, you write them yourself and we help you with issues with respect to them.

Comment: @Compo Yes thanks for the edit.

Comment: yes it worked for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("X:\one path\*.0*") Do For /F "Tokens=* Delims=." %%B In ("%%~xA"
) Do Move /Y "%%A" "X:\some other folder\%%~nA%%B"
```

*Change `X:\one path\` and `X:\some other folder\` as necessary.*

Comment: Yes, it is working as required. Thanks Compo for pointing out the mistakes and providing the solution as well :).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET sourceFolder=source
SET targetFolder=target
FOR /F %%F IN ('dir %sourceFolder% /b') DO (
    SET file=%%F
    MOVE "%sourceFolder%\%%F" "%targetFolder%\!file:.=!"
)
```

Remember to adjust sourceFolder and targetFolder to fit the actual path to your directories.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I don't want to move other folders in the path but I just have to rename and move the files. The one you have suggested will move other folders also right?. Please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: @GaneshChemanchula change `dir /b` to `dir /a-d /b` to exclude directories.